# LM317 as current regulator - problem

Tags: voltage-regulator, constant-current

I'm driving an LM317T from a variable PSU and using it to run 6 x 1W 300mA LEDs in series, approx 3.5v each.

The Output pin goes to a 4.7R resistor then to the LEDs, and the Adjust pin is connected to the "led end" of the resistor.
It's the "Precision current regulator" from the datasheet.

I raise the power voltage, and the LEDs come on.  At about 21.5v the led current reaches 190mA and refuses to go any higher. Changing the resistor to 4.3R had no effect at all! Still 190mA max.

The current should be 1.2/R = 255mA or 279mA, respectively.

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: If you edit your question there's a circuit tool what you can draw schematics please draw a schematic

Comment: Does your variable power supplyy have a current limit?

Comment: What's the voltage across the LM317T? That is, from input to output and from adjust to output.

Comment: Jonathan S: At 21v from the psu, I-to-O is 3.2v. Cranking up the psu to 25v, however  gives I-to-O of 7v, current still 190mA.

Comment: Jonathan S: A-to-O is about 4v.

Comment: Voltage Spike:I can't see a button to edit the question, but The circuit is identical to the one in the datasheet here: https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/LM317/datasheet/precision-current-limiter-circuit-slvs0443877#SLVS0443877   Section 9.3.3

Comment: @GrahamRounce There's an "edit" link below your post, to the left.

Comment: Out of interest, how are you measuring this current?  Where's the ammeter, and what ammeter is it? *very* unlikely it's making a difference, but a combination of a dud ammeter (high res) + putting it in the control loop would have an interesting effect...

Comment: Note that LM317 v drop in current mode is 2.25V PLUS roughly 1.5- 2  V internal drop. See data sheet.

Answer (score 4):

You need a voltage higher than the LED voltage by a few volts for the LM317T to regulate properly. At up to 1A, 2V + 1.25V is typically enough for temperatures above 0°C.

The LED voltage will increase as the current goes up. If you need 21V for the LEDs, then your power supply has to be 24V or a bit more for it to work properly. At that power dissipation level a heatsink is desirable, for higher voltages it becomes necessary.

If 3.5V is the *typical* Vf of the LEDs you may have some that have a bit more and you may require higher than 21V (meaning higher than 24V for the supply). For example, Cree Xlamp bin F white LEDs have 3.6 to 3.8V Vf.

Note also that inserting an ammeter in series will also steal a bit of voltage.

Comment: The variable psu can give as many volts as I like, up to about 50. I've taken it up to 26 (briefly!), and the current still stays at 190mA. I'm thinking that with that low an "adjust" resistance, the resistance of the connecting wires might be having an effect somehow, though the resistor is soldered directly across the Output and Adjust pins. Thanks,

Comment: Have you confirmed the actual voltage with a meter? It’s sounding more like your supply is going into current limit mode, as was suggested already in a comment.

Comment: The voltage and current displayed by the psu seem to be quite accurate.  At the point where the current stops increasing (190mA given by both the psu & meter) the voltage from the psu is about 21v, and the meter shows the same. Across the leds the meter reads about 18.5v. Raising the psu voltage further doesn't change the leds voltage or the current... [So annoying one can't do CRs here without accidentally posting!]

Comment: Have you confirmed the PSU voltage with an independent meter (not the one on the PSU)?

Comment: I've just put another 4.3R across the existing one, ie 2.2R altogether, thinking that should make some difference! But no! It still sticks on 190mA, starting at 21.5v.  It's getting bizarre

Comment: See prev post about using a meter - I think you answered while I was editing because of an accidental "Post".  Can I post a pic somehow?

Comment: Pls see the reply to Peter B, re current limit mode.

Comment: Okay, well you have only two parts plus the PSU, if you're using the schematic we are guessing you are. I suppose you could try swapping out the  regulator for  a new one.

Comment: Spehro P: Yup. An LM317T I've had for a few years works fine.  But a new one tops out at about 190mA. So do 2 other new ones, out of the 10 from ebay.  Fine, so it's a bad batch. Thanks for all the advice.  (Doesn't it seem funny that at least 3 out of 10 should be faulty in exactly the same way?)

Comment: Maybe they're re-marked something else.  Getting parts from eBay is a crap shoot.

Comment: Thanks to all for all the help. None will be wasted!

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the option of low-quality, or internally current-limiting LM317:

Have you verified the resistance of your 4.7Ω resistor? What's the voltage across it during operation?

My interpretation so far: It just gets **really** hot, and thus changes resistance:

300 mA across 4.7Ω, that's 0.42 W (since V=I·R, the power P=V·I=I²·R), and now the thing gets hotter, hence drifts towards, 5Ω, hence increases power consumption to 0.45W, and so on: a vicious, and burnt-smelling, circle, if your resistor isn't made for very high powers (and thus can get rid of the heat fast).

If that is true, you've basically built a thermally controlled control loop :)

Comment: Running for a short while at 25v, the 1/2W resistor stays cold, and the LM317T warms slightly.

Comment: Marcus M: At 25v from the psu the voltage across the 1/2W 2.2R resistor is 0.4v, which works out about right for the current.

Comment: that's not right, though! The resistor is between vout and vadj of the LM317T, right? The LM317 works by adjusting its output exactly so that it's 1.25 V above Vadj. Not 0.4 V. So, something is limiting the current here – It should be 1.25 V / 5 Ω = 0.25 A but it's 0.4V / 5Ω = 0.08 A.

Answer (score 3):

Minimum voltage should be 24.2V. 21V LEDs drop voltage plus 1.2V on resistor, plus minimum 2V IC drop voltage. Also chip requires heatsink. If the chip overheated, internal thermal protection will restrict output current.

Comment: Peter B: Yes, it has, but the indicator for that is not coming on, and anyway I've set it to 5A, to be sure :)

Comment: Just suggestion. Use LM317 as voltage stabilizator. By adjusting voltage value st the wanted current. It will save 1.25V by current 
heat dissipation

Answer (score 0):

As a way to diagnose the part what happens when you set up the 317T as a standard voltage regulator:

1. Input Voltage = 29V
2. Connect the six 3.5V leds in series with your 4.7 ohm resitor.
3. Connect the resistor and LED series string directly to the output pin.
4. The two resistors to set up the output voltage

VO = VREF (1 + R2 / R1)
(neglecting IADJ current)

VO = 29= 1.25(1+ R2/R1)

R2/R1 = 22.2

What voltage do you read across the 4.7 ohm resistor?